# PointerEvent object being returned instead of child data on emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am working on creating a vue component library.  I have build a button component that has data of it's width and left position.  I'm trying to emit that data to the parent (a tabs component) when it's clicked.  I have troubleshooted quite a bit, and have narrowed down most of the problem.  My child component (button) is emitting the correct thing, but it looks like the parent component (tabs) is receiving the value of the click/pointerevent object instead of the data passed on the emit.  I'm certain this is some issue in my parent click handle method, but can't pinpoint what exactly.  I've included code snippets for the components and their click handler methods.

This is pared down, but essentially, I want to emit the width (and eventually left position) of the child button to the parent tab upon clicking the child/button.  I want to assign that emitted width/left position to the slider to move some reactive underlining whenever a button is clicked in the tabs.  I built in a console log statement on the click event that returns the emitted value from the child, and then returns the received value from the parent.  Right now, the child is emitting the correct value when button is clicked, but parent is receiving and trying to assign a PointerEvent object.  Thanks for any feedback!

Child (button) template and relevant script:

```
<template>
  <div class="button @click="click" ref="button"> 
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
  export default {
    name: 'Button',
    emits: [
      'click'
    ],
    data () {
      return {
        width: '',
        left: ''
      }
    },
    setup() {
      const button = ref(null)

      return {
        button
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.left = Math.ceil(this.button.getBoundingClientRect().left)
        this.width = Math.ceil(this.button.getBoundingClientRect().width)
      })
    },
    methods: {
      click () {
        this.$emit('click', this.width)
        console.log(`${this.width} has been emitted to the tabs component`)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Parent (tab) template and relevant script:

```
<template>
  <div class="tabs" @click="updateSliderWidth">
    slot
  </div>
  <div class="slider" :style="sliderWidth">
</template>

<script>
import Button from './Button.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Tabs',
  components: {
   Button
  },
  methods: {
    updateSliderWidth (value) {
      this.sliderWidth = value
      console.log(`${value} has been received and assigned by parent`)
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      sliderWidth: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any problems with your code, except that you don't use the `Button` component in the parent component. Instead you are using a `div`. This would explain, why you're getting a `PointerEvent`. This Event is passed as first parameter to the event, if you don't pass anything explicitly.

Here a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-opruyd?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: Oh it makes sense that it’s the default value.  In usage, I’m putting <Button> where the slot in <Tabs> Is when it goes in my app.  I have the listener attached to the parent div for that reason.  Which is probably why I’m getting the Pointerevent object. I did this because I believed that slot could not have a listener attached.  Is there a workaround implementation?  Thank you for your note!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly. I've updated the stackblitz. Can't you do it this way?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I want it to work (As you've illustrated in the stackblitz).  But, in my implementation, my App.vue is set up as another component <Tabs> wrapped around my <Button> components.  <Tabs> takes a slot (which you can pass a <Button> into).  But currently my <Tabs> is just returning the pointer event because it's placed on the parent container in the <Tabs> component, not the slot/where the button would be coming through in the rendering?  Does that make more sense?

Comment: `<Tabs>                                                                                                                                   
   <Button>                                                                                                                                                                     
   <Button>                                                                                                                                                
 </Tabs>                                                                                                               `